# change web page url to custom url using htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I have created a website which is placed inside bhaskar folder, so my an example url is like:

```
http://localhost/bhaskar/index.php
```

There are also many php pages in my folder.

When I click on any link I would like the index page to redirect on detail.php page. For example this:

```
http://localhost/bhaskar/detail.php?id=137
```

Would need to display the url like this:

```
http://localhost/bhaskar/news/137/.html
```

Is it possible with `.htaccess` file? I have included what I have tried below and also tried other code but none of them have worked for me...

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bhaskar
RewriteRule ^.*News/([0-9]*)/.*\.html$ /fullstory.php?nid=$1
```

Comment: Your htaccess file seems to be routing to "fullstory.php", not "detail.php"

Comment: yes actually this is typing mistake.sorry but in code it is detail.php

Answer (score 0):

This should work the way you want it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bhaskar
RewriteRule news/([0-9]*)/.*\.html$ detail.php?nid=$1 [NC]
```

Just a hint:

It is helpful to add the flag R=301 for testing purpose. Then you will see how the rule is working:

```
RewriteRule news/([0-9]*)/.*\.html$ detail.php?nid=$1 [NC,R=301]
```